# how to extract a same name factor in many dataframe

Tags: r

I have 4 data frame:

temp2011, temp2012, temp2013, temp2014

These dataframe have same column name. (date, temp, humid, rain)
I want to extract a column like this:

```
temp2011$temp
temp2012$temp
temp2013$temp
temp2014$temp
```

It is very hassle, so I change the code like this:

```
col <- "temp"
temp2011$col
temp2012$col
temp2013$col
temp2014$col
```

but this is not work.

How can I do this problem.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to do. Do you just need to get a column from one data set? Changing `temp` to `col` has no effect in my opinion. Are these merged data sets?

Answer (score 2):

Use `[[]]` instead of `$` as `temp2011[[col]]`

Comment: Why should `$` fail in this case?

Comment: `col` is a variable whose value is `temp`, so `temp2011$col` should give `NULL`